# Can't getValues from form inside tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I havn't idea how to getValues from fields of form. Form is one from items inside tabpanel. Cause console throw this:

> "Uncaught TypeError: charform.getValues is not a function"

I didn't face a problem when I get values from form using that:

```
var dataupNew = this.up().items.items[0];
var dataSetNew = dataupNew.getValues();
```

**Here is my code:**

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.forms.Cutarea', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'Les',
    margin: 5,
    height: 600,
    scrollable: true,
    xtype: 'foresto-cutarea',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        cls: 'grbuttons',
        layout: 'card',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'grbuttons',
            layout: 'vbox',
            title: 'Characteristic',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                label: 'number'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'tract'
            }, {
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                label: 'task',
                name: 'targetUsing'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'save',
                cls: 'grbuttons',
                margin: 10,
                ui: 'confirm',
                handler: function () {
                    var charform = this.up('panel');
                    var charSet = charform.getValues();

                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/api/characteristic/',
                        method: 'POST',
                        params: charSet
                    });
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

I wish that handler to do POST query. But now I have this:

> Uncaught TypeError: charform.getValues is not a function

Comment: Did you tried to change your handler function to arrow function?

Comment: Where you are using [form](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) ?

Comment: @PatrykUszyński i down't know how it used in Extjs handler. For example this don't work : handler: function () { var charform = this.up  => charform.getValues(); }

Comment: @RohitSharma form- is one from items of tabpanel

Comment: `this.up('panel')` returns you your Characteristic panel, which isn't a form

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use this.up('panel') to be in tabpanel scope, then you need this.up('form') to get the actual form finally you can get your values

Check this working example [Extjs Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2pin)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Les',
            margin: 5,
            height: 600,
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            scrollable: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                layout: 'card',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    title: 'Characteristic',
                    items: [ {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        label: 'tract'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'save',
                        margin: 10,
                        handler: function () {
                            var charpanel = this.up('panel');
                            var charform = charpanel.up('form');
                            var charSet = charform.getValues();

                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: '/api/characteristic/',
                                method: 'POST',
                                params: charSet
                            });
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```